# Adding extra constness causes compiler error

Tags: c++

This compiles fine on GCC 8.2:

```
class M
{
public:
    const Pointer* getPointer() const {return _ptr;}
private:
    Pointer* _ptr{nullptr};
};
```

but when I add another const to the function:

```
class M
{
public:
    const Pointer* const getPointer() const {return _ptr;}
private:
    Pointer* _ptr{nullptr};
};
```

I get the compiler error:

```
error: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]
```

Why would it not let me add additional const-ness? Since when was extra const bad?

Comment: It's not bad but it is unneeded.  You return by value so the `const` is superfluous.

Comment: How are you calling `getPointer ()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because returning a `const` something by value like here makes no difference with or without.

For example:

```
const int GetMyInt()
{
  int k = 42;
  return k;
}

//later..
int ret = GetMyInt();
// modify ret.
```

Because the returned value from `GetMyInt` will be copied into `ret` anyway (not taking (N)RVO into account), having `GetMyInt` return `const` makes no difference.

Normally this is a warning because it's superfluous code but `-Werror` turns every warning into an error so there's that.

Comment: I understand your example, but in my example I want to return a pointer which cannot be modified and can only call const methods?

Comment: @user997112 Your pointer is returned by value so it is copied on the calling side, so saying *which cannot be modified* can't be done from the return type. The caller decides to where this return value is copied.

Comment: @user997112 But nothing can ever modify the pointer returned even when it's not `const`. You cannot do e.g. `getPointer() += 4`. And at the same time, nothing can prevent you from assigning that pointer to a modifiable one, even if it was returned as `const`.

Answer (score 5):

The `const` qualifier has no effect in this position, since the returned value is a prvalue of non-class type and therefore cannot be modified anyway.

Notice that the compiler message says `-Werror=`, meaning that it's normally a warning (so the code is not wrong, but warning-worthy). It has been turned into an error by your compilation settings.